# Possible to bind virtual element without binding to a container?

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

In the current version of jQuery Mobile it seems to be necessary to keep all data-role="page" elements on one level (at least when one wants to establish links between them). Since I am using knockout to dynamically produce pages, I have the requirement to bind virtual elements directly, e.g. in

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1"><h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1></div>
<!-- ko text: name --><!-- /ko -->
```

I want to bind one model A to page1 and one model B to the virtual element (which is a template: foreach binding in the real application). More detailed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/t3Cyd/3/

Is this doable somehow?

Comment: I don't know about KO, but you can add listeners on `pagecreate` of each page separately. In case you want to do something when pages are shown (`pageContainer` events) it's not possible UNLESS you place each page in a different `pageContainer`. This way, each page will act as an individual page with its own bindings.

Comment: You might checkout the knockout `with` binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html

Comment: @Omar The documentation says (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/) that the pagecontainer _currently_ is a singleton, I therefore didn't bother using more than one container per html page. Is it possible to use more than one pagecontainer in 1.4.2?

Comment: You can use, check this comment https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865#issuecomment-31392277

Comment: @Omar Thanks, I tried to use multiple pagecontainers and it works in general, but the navigation seems to be shaky. I tried to navigate between containers here: http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/UE9Mp/4/.

Comment: I'm checking it. It looks like `pageContainer` doesn't function the same it used to be on jQM 1.3. I'll play around for a bit ;)

Comment: It's not gonna work, sorry for the _misleading_ piece of hint =) It used to work normally on 1.3, but now, with the `pagecontainer` widget it's nearly impossible. It works, however, it requires extra coding/hacking. So, you're stuck with `pagecontainer` events unfortunately..Join us [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7283).

Comment: @Omar It wasn't misleading, it was a clarification. I may have to use multiple .html pages, since they have individual page containers (the body).

Comment: _Single Page Model_ is the same, pages will be loaded into `body` (`pageContainer`) via Ajax. I should start learning KO.

Comment: @Omar ...and I should learn jQM ;) Knockout is great, but it does not play nicely with jQM. Since it is the only JavaScript MVC (MVVM actually) framework I have used, I cannot say much about the competition like Angular JS (I don't like that its functionality overlaps with jQuery) or Ember or Backbone (to name a few).

Comment: There should be a way to get them work properly. I know nothing but jQM, I'll try some basic KO with JQM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information I would say you have 3 options:

(1) Wrap your virtual element in another virtual element or div and use the with binding.

```
<!-- ko with: modelForPage2 -->
    <!-- ko text: name --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

(2) Use the template binding in the virtual element and use the data property to supply a new context.

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'page2_template', data: modelForPage2 } --><!-- /ko -->
```

(3) Create your own custom binding that supports virtual elements and apply bindings to descendants. This is just an example to lead you in the right direction:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindModel = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var newContext = new ModelA();
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(newContext, element);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.bindModel = true;
```

Comment: Thank you. My question was not precise enough. I am quiet sure that all these solutions require the virtual element to be bound first. The "with" will just change the context within the current bind. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/5X7pL/ will not work, because the virtual element is not bound and will not look at "ModelBInstance". What I want is to bind the virtual element without being dependent on parent DOM elements (other than comments).

Comment: I accept the answer anyway since I am now quiet convinced that my original plan does not work and the examples got me on another, more feasible track; I divide my viewmodel into subfunctions (VM.modelA, VM.modelB), apply VM to the whole page and use "with" bindings to scope, example: http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/t3Cyd/4/

Comment: Funny enough I was replying to your first comment suggesting you could do that but I forgot to hit Send. Glad to hear you found a solution.